edit /path/to/file returns e363
When I run:
:edit /home/yt75534/dymoval/src/dymoval_tutorial/dymoval_tutorial.ipynb

I get e363 which surprises me a bit given that such a file is about 980 lines.
I may try to increase the value of maxmempattern as suggested here but that sounds like a workaround. Interestingly enough, the file got opened anyways.
Also, interestingly enough,
:echo filereadable(/home/yt75534/dymoval/src/dymoval_tutorial/dymoval_tutorial.ipynb)

returns 1.
I would be fine also in a method to check beforehand if I will get such an error, for example with an hypothetic checkfile() that takes a filename as input and returns a boolean to say if the file will run out of memory or not.

Could you tell us what is the assigned filetype of your .pynb file on your system and what are the relevant plugins associated to that filetype? I suspect that the message is triggered by the corresponding syntax definition associated to that filetype.

There we go! It associates a json filetype. And it is most likely the problem that you mentioned. How to fix?

json is a reasonable filetype for an .ipynb file. I suspect that it contains large binaries (e.g. images) that make the json parsing to fail. Do you confirm that? Can you share the file somehow such that we can validate that hypothesis.

Yes. The file contains a picture.

Thanks for the feedback! Could you tell us what is the size of the corresponding line? Is the trick that I'm proposing solving your issue?

Not sure if I get you question, but there are several lines that have more than  85000 columns. That line starts with "image/png" Yes, they look quite a lot of columns!

Thanks for that answer. This is indeed what I expected. I fear that 85000 columns are the origin of the problem. I believe changing synmaxcol to a lower value (e.g. 300) will fix your problem. Do you confirm?

I suspect that the syntax check to be at the origin of the message.
I would limit the maximum size of the lines to be checked for syntax (that most probably contains binaries) with the following setting:
set synmaxcol=300

You can make change only for the json filetype with having a ftplugin\after\json.vim:
setlocal synmaxcol=300

